# Generate json with laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to generate JSON with laravel blade template

$articles is a collection and when i do this

Controller:

```
return view('eblogger::content.blog.json.home')->withArticles($articles[0]->toArray());
```

View :

```
{
    'data': [
        {
            'id': {{ $articles['id'] }},
            'name': "{{ $articles['name'] }}"
        }
    ]
}
```

i got in chrome devtools this object :

[image]

it's ok, it returns an object.

But when i use blade features

Controller:

```
return view('eblogger::content.blog.json.home')->withArticles($articles->toArray());
```

View **(edited with a more specific example )** :

```
{
    'data': [
        @foreach($articles['data'] as $article)
           @can('read_this_article', $article)
           {
            'id': {{ $article['id'] }},
            'name': "{{ $article['name'] }}",
            'localization' : "{{getLocalization($article['address'])}}"
           }
           @endcan
        @endforeach
    ]
}
```

it returns a non object like a string

[image]

Is there a way to use laravel blade template to generate Json ?

**Edit**

I'm aware that there is a json helper to generate Json from object. But what i need is a way to create a custom json. I need to check authorisations and other treatments before sending the response.

**conclusion**

I managed to set up the generation. the problem was very simple. I forgot to put a comma after the objects. I am well aware that it is a diversion from the proper use of blade.

@mdexp give me this link: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources

indeed, it's the right way to construct an API

> When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits
>   between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually
>   returned to your application's users. Laravel's resource classes allow
>   you to expressively and easily transform your models and model
>   collections into JSON.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the inbuilt serializer?

Comment: it's not just serialize an object. i want to create a custom response

Comment: but that output you are asking for, can multiple ways of achieving in Laravel. Your way seems non optimal, what is so special about yours?

Comment: i want to check some authorisations , hide some columns, eventually make some treatements before sending the response. it seems more easy if i use blade and i don't know how to make differently

Comment: it is not, i will write up an answer if you spec out the examples you want. The problem is you can easily generate invalid json.

Comment: thanks for the time spent answering me. I found my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at this:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#json-responses

You don't need to create a Blade View and customly build your JSON, use what Laravel provides.

```
return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: To generate my JSON i need to use some features of blate template ( can , foreach, if ... ) so the json helper is not good for me

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are using these language constructs (foreach, etc.) to output a data structure you previously built. Example: If you want to output an Array to JSON you don't have to build a Blade view for that, just use the Response Generator and it will return the full array structure. Try it!

Comment: it's ok, now i uses eloquent  API resource, it's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just pass the $articles collection to the view:

```php
return view('eblogger::content.blog.json.home')->withArticles($articles);
```

Then in the view you can simply use the code below wherever you need to output your json payload:

```php
{
    'data': [
        {{ $articles->toJson() }}
    ]
}
```

Furthermore, if you need to print only some fields about your articles, you can do it like this:

```php
{
    'data': [
        {{ $articles->map->only('id', 'title', 'more-attributes...')->toJson() }}
    ]
}
```

Otherwise, as @Alexander said, creating views just to build JSON is not the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: but i want to generate a custom JSON. I don't want to just serialize my object. I want to check authorizations, hide some columns ...

Comment: Are you building an API? If so then your approach is wrong and what you are looking for is [API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources)